# what attribute will change when we copy image from folder to another folder

Tags: php, image, date

I would like to know what attribute will change when we copy image from folder to another folder php.
Like "*name*", "*date*", "*file size*", etc ..
I've check the "*access date*", "*created date*", "*modified date*". But no success. None of them changed.
[image]

Please help.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i check, when we copy image from the same server, it won't change the "*modified date*", but when we upload from a server to another server, it will.

For example: Upload an image from local to server through *filezilla*, the "*modified date*" will change.

[image]